# silverlight4 exception ( debugging resource strings are not available............. )

Tags: c#, string, debugging, resources, silverlight-4.0

I am getting these error message while we logout from application or when we click on logout buuton

Someone can help me regarding this issue because I m new to silver light technology also I m not to find this issue why it happening and on internet I m not find any relevant article on it

Description of error:
System.argument null exception:[argumentnull_generic ]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are not available .often the key and argument provided sufficient information to diagnose the problem.see............,...,......

Comment: Post your code where you get this error!

Comment: I wil post the. Code but can u suggest me whether it is a code issue or browser . because i got this message on client side

Answer (score 1):

These Errors are generic. This may be as a result of some un-handled exceptions in your silverlight application. I would suggest to put Try-Catch block on vulnerable code and debug. Surely this will help you.